# TV series about pre-historic travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv, prehistoric

I saw somewhere a new TV series. Here's what I remember:

Sometime in the future, when the Earth could no longer support life (or something similar), a group of people goes to the past of the Earth.

They found themselves in pre-historic times. They try to build a colony etc.

Does anyone know something about this series?

Comment: ...This sounds *exactly* like Terra Nova, which hasn't started airing yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That definitely sounds like [Terra Nova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_Nova_%28TV_series%29). It will be on Fox September 26th.