# Science fiction TV series - Time traveling family go to a colony in the age of the dinosaurs. Father is a cop

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Key plot points;

- Humans go **back in time** to the **age of dinosaurs** as the planet is in trouble
- The series focus is on a family of four
- The father is something like a cop in the new colony.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [this topic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for help on how to format your question, and specifically story identification questions. In its current state, your question has very little actual detail.

Comment: So, the main characters are a family of four, out of all of the humans that went back? Or did just the four go back in time to establish a colony? If the former, was it all of humanity or just a subset? Did they fight dinosaurs? Experience plague or famine? Agree on a political system?

Comment: I'm at a loss why this has attracted downvotes and close votes. It's very answerable and I challenge any of the close-voters to identify another show with a time traveling family who go to a colony in the age of the dinosaurs where the dad is a cop.

Comment: @Valorum  -  I find it easier to vote to close and then retract vote/reopen if someone comes up with an answer.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I think the problem with this question was that it just needed a bit of spit and polish to remove the formatting problems and a better title. You could easily have added those rather than clicking the close button.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/tv-series-about-pre-historic-travel

Comment: @Otis  - Agreed, but I think this should be kept and that should be the dupe. This has a better answer.

Comment: This is extremely vague; doesn't even specify a timeframe, or whether the show was in colour. Or what station it was on. Or what country the OP saw it in. I can well understand the down/close votes - have a couple more!

Answer (score 23):

Could this be [Terra Nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_Nova_(TV_series))?

The father is a cop and the show features a family traveling in time to an alternate Earth with [dinosaurs](http://terranova.wikia.com/wiki/Dinosaurs).

Comment: Terra Nova was my first thought when I saw the question title; as expected someone already answered it. :)

Comment: I miss this show.

Comment: Holy crap, that's Jeffrey Mace. How did I not make that connection?!

Comment: A team that trusts, is a team that triumphs....